# using JOINS to concatenate user's data from multiple tables MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I need to export the data from several tables into a .csv file. I've written the CSV output code but now I need to structure the query properly.

Each table contains a `USER_ID` field. This field is used to relate the user's data from one table to another. I need to grab all the data from these tables, with each user's information fully represented on a single row.

simple example of what I need:

```
TABLE A
|USER ID | NAME | FAVORITE_COLOR | AGE |
|007     |James | black          | 46  |
----------------------------------------

TABLE B
|USER ID | JOB | LOCATION | NOTES    |
|007     |Agent| N/A      | cool guy | 
--------------------------------------


JOINED OUTPUT I NEED (albeit with many more users / tables):
|USER ID | NAME | FAVORITE_COLOR | AGE | JOB | LOCATION | NOTES    |
|007     |James | black          | 46  |Agent| N/A      | cool guy |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know this can be accomplished with `joins` but I'm not sure how to make a query which selects ALL the users, and joins ALL their data from several tables, so that each user is a single row with all their data.

Any help or a code nudge in the right direction is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 select t1.USER ID , NAME , FAVORITE_COLOR , AGE ,JOB , LOCATION , NOTES 
 from TABLE1 t1 
 INNER JOIN table2 t2  
 ON t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID
```

EDIT>

if you have 3 or 4 tables then just join them you can add this

```
  INNER JOIN table3 t3  
  ON t2.USER_ID = t3.USER_ID
  INNER JOIN table4 t4  
  ON t3.USER_ID = t4.USER_ID
```

Comment: how would this change with more than 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select t1.*,t2.* from table_1 as t1 left join table_2 as t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following tables

```
TABLE A
|USER ID | NAME | FAVORITE_COLOR | AGE |
|007     |James | black          | 46  |
|008     |John  | Doe            | 77  |
|010     |Amy   | McClain        | 26  |
----------------------------------------

TABLE B
|USER ID | JOB | LOCATION | NOTES    |
|007     |Agent| N/A      | cool guy |
|010     |Agent| MI       | babe     | 
--------------------------------------

SELECT TableA.*, TableB.*
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableA.[USER ID] = TableB.[USER ID]
```

Will will pull all records found in `TableA` regardless of if there is a matching record in `TableB`.  Here is what the results would look like:

```
|USER ID | NAME | FAVORITE_COLOR | AGE | JOB | LOCATION | NOTES    |
|007     |James | black          | 46  |Agent| N/A      | cool guy |
|008     |John  | Doe            | 77  |Null | Null     | Null     |
|010     |Amy   | McClain        | 26  |Agent| MI       | babe     |
```

By changing the `LEFT JOIN` to a `INNER JOIN` you can force the query to pull only records that are found in both tables.  Here is what the results would look like:

```
|USER ID | NAME | FAVORITE_COLOR | AGE | JOB | LOCATION | NOTES    |
|007     |James | black          | 46  |Agent| N/A      | cool guy |
|010     |Amy   | McClain        | 26  |Agent| MI       | babe     |
```

Comment: Thank you. What changes would need to be made for more than 2 tables? I'm working with 3-4.

Comment: It depends on the type of join needed and the result you are looking for.  I think you just need to familiarize yourself better with joins.  [**Jeff Atwood**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) explanation on Joins.  [**Code Project**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) explanation on Joins.  [**w3schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) explanation on Joins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
$qry = "SELECT t1.USER_ID,t1.NAME,t1.FAVORITE_COLOR,t1.AGE,t2.JOB,t2.LOCATION,t2.NOTES FROM TABLE_1 as t1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 as t2 ON t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID";
```